# Angular JS orderBy 2 properties not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to sort the car inventory of my app by `make` and `model` alphabetically and I am only able to sort it by make. I also tried to sort by `make` and `year` but again it is only sorting by `make`.

Does orderBy sort alphabetically and numerically?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row gallery-container" ng-init="getCars();">
  <div class="inventory-title">
    <h2>Current Inventory</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="car-container">
  <div ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:['make','model']">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-ms-10 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-ms-offset-1">
      <a ng-href="/#/car/{{car._id}}" class="no-style-link-thumb">
        <div class="thumbnail inventory-car-containter">
            <img ng-src="{{car.picture.url | fpConvert: {filter:'sharpen', w:750, h:375} }}" />
          <div class="caption text-center">
            <p class="yr-mk-mdl">{{car.year}} {{car.make}} {{car.model}}</p>
            <p class="price">{{car.price}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my car model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (mongoose, models) => {
// Defines the car schema
  let CarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     make: {type: String, required: true},
     model: {type: String, required: true},
     year: {type: String, required: true},
     createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the createdAt parameter equal to the current time
CarSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  var now = new Date();
  if (!this.createdAt) {
      this.createdAt = now;
  }
  next();
});

// Exports the CarSchema for use elsewhere.
let Car = mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema);
models.Car = Car;
};
```

I want it to sort a list like this:
-Aston Martin DB5
-Ferrari 250 California Spyder SWB
-Ferrari 458
-Porsche 911

This is how it is currently sorting the list:
-Aston Martin DB5
-Ferrari 458
-Ferrari 250 California Spyder SWB
-Porsche 911

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the expression is computed (evaluated?) by angular - instead of passing `['make','model']`, you should try the following:

```
  <div ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:'make + model'">
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and it caused it to not order at all. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I gave it another shot and it breaks the orderBy and it just goes back to the way it was before it was sorted at all. It seems to work fine of the jsfiddle but it breaks the sort in my code.